# could std::sort with not strict weak ordering comparator work as topological sorting?

Tags: c++, sorting, strict-weak-ordering

I do know that I should follow strict weak ordering for c++ comparator. And the main reason is that `!(a > b) && !(b > a)` should act as equivalence operator.

But the problem is only sorting where you don't need equivalence operator not like `std::set`.

For example, there is vector of sets and if set A is proper subset of B, then after sorting, index of set A should be smaller than index of set B.

So assume that you write comparator like this

```
bool comparator(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B) const {
    // if A is proper subset of B, return true
    // otherwise, return false
}
```

Then does `std::sort` with this comparator always work like topological sorting?

plus)

thanks for Oliver Charlesworth for missing information.

I really want to know that such comparator works with like quick sort or insertion sort (some famous comparison-based sorting algorithms) as topological sort.

Comment: Are you asking (A) what will happen if you provide `std::sort` that comparator, or (B) whether this comparator could be used as the basis of a topological sort?  The answer to (A) is certainly **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I mean (A). And it may have undefined behavior because std::sort can be implemented many ways. I think I missed some conditions. My real question is If the sorting algorithm are like quick sort or heap sort or insertion sort then the result are correct like in topological sort.

Comment: No. It works neither in theory nor in practice. Qsort is no toposort. If you need a toposort algo, use one.

Comment: you may also take a look at [this iso paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4367.html) for a review of the issue ...

Comment: Note that proper subset is almost a strict weak ordering, the only problem is that it is partial (you can have two sets where neither is a subset of the other). If you can guarantee that doesn't happen in your data set, then this comparator will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is likely not to work. `std::sort` contract requires a strict weak ordering comparator; violating it results in undefined behavior. BTW, I've seen several times libstdc++ `std::sort` brutally crash (reading elements outside the container, IIRC) for this kind of comparator "relaxing".